# Where can I find a good boilerplate bashrc?

Tags: shell, bashrc

I've used unix/linux at work in the past, and recently started developing on a Mac. I'd always (lovingly) borrow co-workers' bashrc's for a good starting point, such as common aliasing and commands, but I'm a bit at a loss when it comes from building my own from scratch.

Is there a resource that has good "boilerplate" bashrc files (or other shell config files, for that matter) that will have most if not all of what I want -- even stuff I don't know I need yet? ;)

Comment: a lot of examples are at github, take look at the dotfiles.

Comment: I was sort of hoping rather than sifting through a bunch of peoples' personal preferences on github there was a nice resource like http://html5boilerplate.com/ for configuration files

Comment: I see, but bash is not markup and there is no such thing like boilerplate. rather public bashrc files and they are always different and depend on what you have installed. I also write this as comment, because it's possible someone has a good resource for you.

Comment: understood-- I'll poke around github, but I think it would be very cool if you could generate a bashrc file based on what you want/need somewhere...

Comment: @bersch "boilerplate" does not necessarily, or even usually, refer to "markup" and the OP's terminology here is completely normative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code E.g., the skeleton stuff your system uses to create a default `.bashrc` is boilerplate.

Comment: @goldilocks ok, agree, however there is still no such thing bashrc-boilerplate.

Comment: I keep all of my custom "dot files" in git and the first time I log into a new home directory I do a git init, and a git pull and then I have all my settings that I'm used to. I have branches for different OSes and shells.

Comment: @hyphen this, yes! That's what I was going for.

Comment: @bersh Q.v. `/etc/skel/.bashrc` == bashrc-boilerplate.  The system copies this into new home directories.

Comment: lol, ok you win!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Arch Wiki has some [example aliases and generic commands](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bashrc#Configuration) that will work in the majority of `.bashrc` files providing you are using systemd and have `sudo` installed.

This highlights the problem with the approach you are seeking, and one of the undesirable side effects of copying and pasting someone else's idea of a standard configuration into your shell 's config. You run two risks: introducing material that is not suitable for your environment or, much worse, adding configuration options that are just plain wrong but that the person before you had added because they were similarly misinformed. As an example, look through some `.bashrc` files in git/hg repositories and note how many export a TERM...

You are much better off starting with whatever your distro ships and then adding options that are familiar and tested by you, documented in the `man` page or—if you do want to use options in other people's configs—add them one at a time and make sure they do what they are supposed to do.